# How is load average calculated on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, load-average

On Linux, the load average is the average number of processes that are either runnable or waiting averaged over the past 1, 5 and 15 minutes.

On OpenBSD (and *possibly* other BSDs, but neither the quote nor the context really says), [load average](http://www.undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20090715034920) is "the number of processes which have (wanted to) run at least once in the most recent 5-second window, with a degradation over time".

However, I was unable to locate information on how load average is actually defined on *FreeBSD*.

**What is the exact meaning of the load average numbers on FreeBSD?**

Comment: Comment: Since recently (Dec 2016?), kernel threads counts towards the load average on OpenBSD. An idle OpenBSD system will therefore have a load of about 1.

Comment: Ah sorry. :/ On irc discussions went that this could indeed be a bug in FreeBSD 11 as 10.2 does not behave the same way.

Comment: @larsemil I have no idea what you are referring to. Are you saying that in FreeBSD 11, the existence of load averages is a bug?

Comment: No. But how it handles it. I dont know, just quoting what was said in the FreeBSD IRC channel.

Comment: Just to an update to my previous comment here: OpenBSD 6.2 now does no longer include kernel threads when calculating the load average. That was something happening in OpenBSD 6.1 only, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

In the tradition of UTSL, I've pasted in the code that runs the calculation.  Here, `nrun=sched_load()` is the total "ready to run" processes this instant and avg is pointing to a structure with 3 fixed point numbers (1,5,15 minutes).  cexp are magic numbers to decay the values for 1,5 and 15 minutes.  For reference, this is in `/usr/src/sys/kern/kern_synch.c` ... which I might recommend as a fascinating read.

In FreeBSD, what most surprises people about responsive machines with high load averages is that a spot awakening of a large number of processes can inflate the numbers greatly.  IE: if 400-ish processes all awake together (web servers or database servers sometimes do this.)

```
/*
 * Compute a tenex style load average of a quantity on
 * 1, 5 and 15 minute intervals.
 */
static void
loadav(void *arg)
{
    int i, nrun;
    struct loadavg *avg;

    nrun = sched_load();
    avg = &averunnable;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        avg->ldavg[i] = (cexp[i] * avg->ldavg[i] +
            nrun * FSCALE * (FSCALE - cexp[i])) >> FSHIFT;
    /*
     * Schedule the next update to occur after 5 seconds, but add a
     * random variation to avoid synchronisation with processes that
     * run at regular intervals.
     */
    callout_reset_sbt(&loadav_callout,
        SBT_1US * (4000000 + (int)(random() % 2000001)), SBT_1US,
        loadav, NULL, C_DIRECT_EXEC | C_PREL(32));
}
```